# Bigquery SQL - List the top vendors in each country, for each year in the dataset

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to join 2 tables and extract the top vendor by country by year.

The original ORDERS table looks like this :

```
country_name    date_local  vendor_id   gmv_local   
Taiwan       2012-10-02     2870          559.6     
Taiwan       2012-10-02     3812          573.5     
Singapore    2012-10-02     941           778.6     
Singapore    2014-10-02     13            120.6     
Thailand     2014-10-02     227           563.6
```

This table is merged with the vendor table

```
id  vendor_name             country_name
2870    A House             Taiwan
941     B House             Singapore
227     C House             Thailand
```

I would like to extract the year from the "date_local" column into timestamp format, where the items in the Year column will look like "2012-01-01T00:00:00" from the original date format of "2012-10-02"

Then I would like to list out the top 2 vendors by year for each country in total gmv.

The resulting table should look like this:

```
year                    country_name    vendor_name     total_gmv
2012-01-01T00:00:00     Singapore        A House        1119.76
2012-01-01T00:00:00     Singapore        B House         819.63
2012-01-01T00:00:00     Taiwan           C House         119.6
2012-01-01T00:00:00     Taiwan           D House         119.6
2012-01-01T00:00:00     Bangkok          9 House         119.6
2014-01-01T00:00:00     Singapore        A House         2119.76
2014-01-01T00:00:00     Singapore        B House         1819.63
2014-01-01T00:00:00     Taiwan           C House         1019.6
2014-01-01T00:00:00     Taiwan           D House         919.6
2014-01-01T00:00:00     Bangkok          9 House         189.6
```

Based on, among others, some previous guidance here, I've come up with the following query:

```
SELECT
    Ord.country_name,
    vn.vendor_name,
    EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) AS year,
    ROUND(SUM(Ord.gmv_local), 2) AS total_gmv
FROM ORDERS AS Ord
LEFT JOIN `primeval-falcon-306603.foodpanda_BI_Exercise.Vendors` AS vn
    ON Ord.vendor_id = vn.id
GROUP BY
    Ord.country_name,
    vn.vendor_name,
    EXTRACT(year FROM date_local)
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country_name, EXTRACT(year FROM date_local)
                           ORDER BY total_gmv DESC) <= 2
ORDER BY
    Ord.country_name DESC,
    total_gmv DESC;
```

But keep getting this error message: SELECT list expression references column date_local which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [4:23]

So unfortunately not even able to see if I'm getting the result I'm looking for.

Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
with ORDERS (country_name,date_local,vendor_id,gmv_local) as(
select 'Taiwan', Date('2012-10-02'),     2870 ,         559.6     union all
select 'Taiwan',       Date('2012-10-02'),     3812,          573.5     union all
select 'Taiwan',       Date('2012-10-02'),     3813,          555.5     union all
select 'Singapore',    Date('2012-10-02'),     941,           778.6     union all
select 'Singapore',    Date('2014-10-02'),     13,            120.6     union all
select 'Thailand',     Date('2014-10-02'),     227,           563.6   
)
,vendor(id,  vendor_name, country_name) as(
select 2870,    'A House','Taiwan' union all
select 3812,    'D House','Taiwan' union all
select 3813,    'F House','Taiwan' union all
select 941,     'B House','Singapore' union all
select 13,   'E House','Singapore' union all
select 227,     'C House','Thailand'
)
select country_name,vendor_name,year,total_gmv from(
SELECT
    Ord.country_name,
    vn.vendor_name,
    EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) AS year,
    ROUND(SUM(Ord.gmv_local), 2) AS total_gmv,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country_name,EXTRACT(year FROM date_local)) rn
FROM ORDERS AS Ord
LEFT JOIN vendor AS vn
    ON Ord.vendor_id = vn.id
GROUP BY
    Ord.country_name,
    vn.vendor_name,
    EXTRACT(year FROM date_local)
ORDER BY
    Ord.country_name DESC,
    total_gmv DESC
)a where a.rn <= 2
```